# Best Python library for face recognition

Tags: machine-learning, python

I need to use an accurate library for face recognition in my attendance python project.

I used the `face-recognition` but I could no get the desired result. Is there any way to get 99% accuracy? I have more than 1000 students to register and then need to recognise them.

Comment: What results are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I want to recommend this [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.06655.pdf) (TABLE IV). It's not the most recent, but the algorithm families haven't changed much.

If you were referring to the `face_recognition` library, then it uses the `dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1` model, which is indeed somewhat outdated.

In my opinion, you should compare the two models [`Facenet`](https://github.com/timesler/facenet-pytorch) and [`SphereFace2`](https://github.com/ydwen/opensphere). The second one is quite new. And for training the first one, Google used a huge amount of data (more than for any other model).